Passing Data structure and Retrieve Data structure in ReactJs / Aps.Net Core 7 Web application
Frontend
-> This is the my API(backend) call method and Sending object structure
const response = await axiosInstance.put(UPDATE_USEREMAIL, {
            userEmail
});

-> This axiosInstance is,
import axios from 'axios';
import { HOST_API_KEY } from './globalConfig';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({ baseURL: HOST_API_KEY });

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => response, // if return the succesfull response
    (error) =>              // if has error
        Promise.reject(
            (error.response && error.response) || 'General Axios Error happend'
        )
);

export default axiosInstance;

Backend
-> This is the Retrieving object structure
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace backend_dotnet7.Core.Dtos.Auth
{
    public class UpdateUserEmailDto
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Email is required")]
        public string? Email { get; set; }
    }
}

-> This is the API method
[HttpPut]
[Route("updateUserEmail")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult<UpdateUserEmailResponseDto>> updateUserEmail(UpdateUserEmailDto 
updateUserEmailDto)     
{
    try
    {
        var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        if (userId is null)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, "Can't find user, Please contact 
            admin");                                  
        }

        var isExists = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        if (isExists is null)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound, "User does not exists");
        }

        if(updateUserEmailDto.Email is null)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, "null");
        }

        var isValid = await _userEmailService.EmailValidation(updateUserEmailDto.Email);

        if (!isValid)
        { 
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, "User Email is invalid");
        }

        isExists.Email = updateUserEmailDto.Email;

        var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(isExists);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            var errors = result.Errors.Select(e => e.Description).ToList();
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, errors);
        }

        var userInfoObject = new UserInfoResult
        {
            Id = isExists.Id,
            FirstName = isExists.FirstName,
            LastName = isExists.LastName,
            Email = isExists.Email,
            UserName = isExists.UserName,
            CreatedAt = isExists.CreatedAt,
            Roles = isExists.Roles
        };

        return new UpdateUserEmailResponseDto
        {
            userInfo = userInfoObject,
        };

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _userLogger.LogError(ex.Message);
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}

-> Above codes is used in my project for update user email, I chacked by using swagger, then it perfectly working, but I checked using frontend code, then Always update email to 'abc@gmail.com' and not given Error... ?????
-> Can you suggest the error in my task ???
According to the above details,
I checked in backend code by using swagger, then it properly work and update the database correctly.
But I checked by connecting the backend to frontend, then Not given Error....
But Always update database to 'abc@gamil.com'....
I can't find solution for this problem ????

It must be hardcoded somewhere in frontend code (Not backend because you saying with swagger it works fine). Other than that what you are describing is not possible and doesn't make any sense, Do a global search for abc@gamil.com.
Inspect the network tab and see what is getting passed.
Also to match backend expectations update below code?
const response = await axiosInstance.put(UPDATE_USEREMAIL, {
    Email: userEmail
});

